# AngularJS Communication between ng-repeat and controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I've just started using AngularJS, and as a project I decided to build a simple app for managing bookmarks. I want to be able to maintain a list of bookmarks and add/remove items. I'm using Django with Django REST framework, and Angular.

So far I've written a service to grab the bookmarks from the database, and I can print them to the console from my controller, but ng-repeat doesn't seem to be seeing them.

Here's my code for the service:

```
.factory('BookmarkService', ["$http", function ($http) {
    var api_url = "/api/bookmarks/";
    return {
        list: function () {
            return $http.get(api_url).then(function (response) {
                return response.data
             })
        }
    }
}]);
```

And for the controller:

```
.controller("ListController", 
 ["$scope", "BookmarkService", function ($scope, BookmarkService) {
    $scope.bookmarks = BookmarkService.list();
    console.log($scope.bookmarks);
}]);
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ListController as listCtrl">
    <md-card>
        <md-card-content>
            <h2>Bookmarks</h2>
            <md-list>
                <md-list-item ng-repeat="bookmark in listCtrl.bookmarks">
                    <md-item-content>
                        <div class="md-tile-content">
                            <p>{[{ bookmark.name }]} - {[{ bookmark.url }]}</p> // used interpolateProvider to allow "{[{" instead of "{{"
                        </div>
                        <md-divider ng-if="!$last"></md-divider>
                    </md-item-content>
                </md-list-item>
            </md-list>
        </md-card-content>
     </md-card>
  </div>
```

When I print to the console from the controller I can see a promise object but ng-repeat isn't repeating:
[image of promise object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuHGA.png)

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me to find my mistake and to understand why it is happening. I'm still not entirely comfortable with how all these parts fit together.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems that I see with the code in question.

The first is that using the controller as syntax (`ng-controller="ListController as listCtrl"`) requires properties to be bound to the controller instance and not to the scope if you address them using the controller name.  In your case,

```
.controller("ListController", 
  ["BookmarkService", function (BookmarkService) {
    this.bookmarks = BookmarkService.list();
    console.log(this.bookmarks);
  }]);
```

The second is that you are assigning a promise to your `$scope.bookmarks` property.  The repeater is expecting an array of objects to iterate over.  You really want to assign the value resolved by the promise to `$scope.bookmarks`.

Instead of this

```
$scope.bookmarks = BookmarkService.list();
```

Do this

```
BookmarkService.list().then(function(result){
  this.bookmarks = result;
});
```

The final version of your controller should look something like this

```
.controller("ListController", 
  ["BookmarkService", function (BookmarkService) {
    this.bookmarks = BookmarkService.list();
    console.log(this.bookmarks);
  }]);
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer fixed that problem.

Comment: I had actually tried that previously. However, there was another issue. The bookmarks don't load when I use the "controller as" syntax i.e. `listCtrl.bookmarks`. They only without it. Do you have any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that before.  When using controller as syntax you need to attach properties to the controller instance and not the `$scope`.  In this case that would look like `.controller("ListController", 
 ["BookmarkService", function (BookmarkService) {
    this.bookmarks = BookmarkService.list();
    console.log(this.bookmarks);
}]);`  Notice the `this` instead of `$scope`

Comment: I see! Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: You're welcome.  I incorporated the controller as part into the answer.  Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. Ng-repeat is not working with promises. So, you can go with two ways:

1. BookmarkService.list().then(function(responce){
   $scope.bookmarks = responce.data;
   });
2. Another way is to create own repiter ^)

[Ng-repeat doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)